# binding progress bar with a method, javafx

Tags: javafx

I have a method which performs some task(reading, writing files and other tasks also) for almost 3 minutes.

I want to bind progress bar in `javafx` which can run with progress of the method.

This is my method

```
    System.out.println("Going to load contract/security:"+new Date());
    Map<Integer,FeedRefData> map = loadContractAndSecurityFromFile(loadFO);
    addIndicesRefData(map);
    BufferedWriter writer = createFile();
    for (FeedRefData feedRefData : map.values()) {
        try {
            updateInstrumentAlias(map, feedRefData);
            String refDataString = feedRefData.toString();
            writer.write(refDataString, 0, refDataString.length());
            writer.newLine();
            writer.flush();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            log.info("Unable to write Quote Object to : " );
        }
    }
    System.out.println("Ref Data File Generated:"+new Date());
```

Comment: Is it a complete code of your method ?

Comment: yes it is complete.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For bind your method with progressbar you should do these steps :

1. Create a task which contains your method.
2. Create a thread which run this task.
3. Bind your progress property with your task property.
   I made this simple example ,just change my code with your method code :

   ```
       public class Bind extends Application {

       public static void main(String[] args) {
           launch(args);
       }

       @Override
       public void start(Stage primaryStage) {

           ProgressBar pb = new ProgressBar();
           pb.setProgress(1.0);

           Button button = new Button("start");
           button.setOnAction((ActionEvent event) -> {
                /*Create a task which contain method code*/
               Task<Void> task = new Task<Void>() {
                   @Override
                   protected Void call() throws Exception {

                       File file = new File("C:\\Users\\Electron\\Desktop\\387303_254196324635587_907962025_n.jpg");
                       ByteArrayOutputStream bos = null;
                       try {
                           FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(file);
                           byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
                           bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                           for (int len; (len = fis.read(buffer)) != -1;) {
                               bos.write(buffer, 0, len);

                               updateProgress(len, file.length());
                               /* I sleeped operation because reading operation is quiqly*/
                               Thread.sleep(1000);
                           }
                           System.out.println("Reading is finished");
                       } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                           System.err.println(e.getMessage());
                       } catch (IOException e2) {
                           System.err.println(e2.getMessage());
                       }
                       return null;
                   }
               };

                   Thread thread = new Thread(task);
                   thread.start();
               /*bind the progress with task*/
                 pb.progressProperty()
                       .bind(task.progressProperty());

           });
           HBox box = new HBox(pb, button);
           Stage stage = new Stage();
           StackPane root = new StackPane();
           root.getChildren().add(box);
           Scene scene = new Scene(root);
           stage.setScene(scene);
           stage.show();

       }

   }
   ```

Operation started :

[image]

Operation finished :

[image]

PS: I used `Thread.sleep(1000)` because my file is so small.You can remove it if your progress time is long.